# Division in MASM Error - Jump within short distance

Tags: assembly, division, masm

I cant figure out nor find any information why I am getting error during compiling my code

```
loop1:
mov edx, 0 ; reset EDX which contains the remainder
XOR ECX,  ECX   ;reset ECX
MOV EDX, EAX
MOV EBX, NUM2   ;num2 = 10, so copy 10 to EBX
CMP EAX, EBX
JNG nextStep
Division:
    SUB EAX, EBX    ; EAX-10
    INC ECX
    CMP EAX, EBX
    JG Division
nextStep:
MOV EDX, EAX        ;move reminder to EDX
MOV EAX, ECX        ;move result of division to EAX
push dx ; save it to stock so to display int he proper order
inc count ; count how many pushes of stack
cmp Eax,0 ; check if the div ends
JL loop1
```

The error that I am getting from compiler is:

```
 008F  0F 8E 009D R                     JNG nextStep
 fib2.ASM(67): warning A5104: Jump within short distance

  49798 + 451946 Bytes symbol space free

  1 Warning Errors
  0 Severe  Errors
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler seems to have used the near jump opcode `0F 8E` for `JNG` even though the jump distance is only 14 bytes away `008F->009D`.  If you explicitly use `JNG Short nextStep` it should generate the short jump opcode `7E` instead.  This is merely a matter of minor efficiency.  It should not affect the actual result.

Comment: Thank you ! This explained my concerns

Answer (score 1):

That's a warning about inefficient code, not an error.

Here's a copy-pasted explanation of what the warning means:

> A `JMP` instruction was used to jump to a `short` label (128 or 
>   fewer bytes before the end of the `JMP` instruction, or 127 or 
>   fewer bytes beyond the instruction). By default the assembler 
>   assumes that jumps are `near` (greater than `short`, but still in one 
>   segment). If a `short` jump is encountered, masm uses a short 
>   form of the `JMP` instruction (2 bytes) rather than the long 
>   form (3 bytes with 16-bit segments or 5 bytes with 32-bit seg- 
>   ments). You can make your code slightly more efficient by 
>   using the `SHORT` operator to specify that a jump is `short` 
>   rather than `near`. For example, using the `SHORT` operator in 
>   the following example saves 1 byte of code:
>
> `jrrp SHORT there`
>
> `there: . ; Less than 127 bytes`
>
> With the 80386 processor, this also applies to conditional 
>   jumps, which can be either short (2 bytes) or near (4 bytes).